# Can Runnable be called immediately?

Tags: android, multithreading

Is it possible to call `Runnable` without `execute`-ing it?

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //TODO your background code
   }
});
```

In iOS a `closure` can be `executed`, or just called like a method. In first case there is a small delay, other code chunk can come first to the loop, in second case right at the time when call is done code is `Runnable` is performed. How is it with Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {...}
runnable.run();
```

and if you need to be able to decide where to execute it depending on your current thread: UI or non-UI, you can do something like this

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()) { ... } else { ... }
```

Some useful information can be found here [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)